# "this" within setTimeout self executing function is undefined

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I know that this within setTimeout will correspond by default to window, so I have been using bind and passing it through to the self executing function, but when setTimeout finally runs (it's fine on the first run, called by TeaBot._manageTeaRound(), but it's not fine when self executing) this is undefined. Here's my code, where am I going wrong? (I have deleted some lines of code which might not be relevant). Thanks for your help :)

```
TeaBot.prototype._manageTeaRound = function(originalMessage, channel){
    var self = this;
    self.teaMaker = this._getUserById(originalMessage.user);

    //now wait 3 minutes for people to send their order
    self._runTimer(self,channel);
}
TeaBot.prototype._runTimer =function(self, channel) {
    // do stuff
    console.log(self.teaMaker.name); //undefined

    var interval = self.interval,
        teaMaker = self.teaMaker;

    console.log("self.interval is " + self.interval);

    if(interval === 0){

        interval++;
        self.interval = interval;

        setTimeout(self._runTimer.bind(self, channel), 180000);

    }else{
        self.interval = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: check out: setInterval / clearInterval . Maybe it's useful for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is problematic:

```
setTimeout(self._runTimer.bind(self, channel), 180000);
```

Function `TeaBot.prototype._runTimer` expects `self` to be the first param - `Function.prototype.bind()` first param is `context` (function's `this`). Try use it like this:

```
setTimeout(self._runTimer.bind(self, self, channel), 180000);
```

Or leave `context` empty, becouse you are not using `this` at all:

```
setTimeout(self._runTimer.bind(undefined, self, channel), 180000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely misunderstood how the first parameter is the context, regardless of parameters I need to pass to the function! Thank you it is now all fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are *not* using the value of `this` inside of `_runTimer`.  You are binding a value `this`, but `_runTimer` couldn't care less.

`_runTimer` cares about its two parameters.  The 1st being the context (`self`).  The way your code is structured, there's no reason to use `.bind` here.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    self._runTimer(self, channel);
}, 180000);
```

(Since you are passing the context (`self`) to the function, it makes no sense to have `_runTimer` be a part of `TeaBot.prototype`, since it needs a context passed to it.)

---

As an alternative, you can drop the `self` parameter, and have `_runTimer` reference `this`.  That's when you would *need* to use `.bind()`.

```
TeaBot.prototype._manageTeaRound = function(originalMessage, channel){
    this.teaMaker = this._getUserById(originalMessage.user);

    //now wait 3 minutes for people to send their order
    this._runTimer(channel);
};
TeaBot.prototype._runTimer = function(channel) {
    // do stuff
    console.log(this.teaMaker.name);

    var interval = this.interval,
        teaMaker = this.teaMaker;

    console.log("this.interval is " + this.interval);

    if(interval === 0){

        interval++;
        this.interval = interval;

        setTimeout(this._runTimer.bind(this, channel), 180000);

    } else{
        this.interval = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out, I've misunderstood how the first parameter for setTimeout IS the context! I set it to undefined and it's now all working :)

Comment: @mfujica: The first parameter to `setTimeout` is the function to run.  The first parameter to `bind` is the context. :-)